# How to get the image coordinates(points) from a picturebox irrespective of panning and zooming

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, zooming

I have got the image coordinates from the Mousedown locations on the Picturebox successfully, be it, various size modes of Picturebox. But facing difficulty in finding the center point after panning operation or zooming operation.
 As for now i am only working in Normal Sizemode of Picturebox to attain the following.

**My main objective::**

***1. to draw a circle with Mousedown location as the center***

***2. Next finding the radius(in terms of pixels) of the circle drawn on the Picturebox(not on the image) which should be same always even after panning and zooming. Even after zoom or pan, if i draw a circle(or ellipse), it should give me radius in terms of image.I know the conversion of points to pixels.***

---

I have implemented panning using Mousedown,up and move events and implemented Zoom using trackbar.
I need help in the following parts for now::
 Condition 1:
I open the image>>Pan it by a certain distance>>Enable a Circle tool>>draw it with a center inside the image boundary and the circle should be drawn then and there
Condition 2:
I open the image>>Draw circle, pan it,circle should be translated by the same amount as the image is panned.
Here is my MouseDown,MouseUp,MouseMove and Paint methods:

***Please tell me if you need any function body or something.Because its just a big messy application that I'm working on***

Tell me if you need anything.Open to any other design approach conforming to my main objective mentioned above.

***EDIT after TerryBozzio's answer::***

```
        Bitmap _bmp;
        private bool _isMouseDown = false;
        private Point _mouseDownLocation = Point.Empty;
        int _xDifference, _yDifference;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _bmp = RenderImageOfSpecifiedSize(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\2 duck.bmp");
            _pictureBox.Image = _bmp;
        }

        private Bitmap RenderImageOfSpecifiedSize(string fileLocation)
        {
            //return new Bitmap(new Bitmap(fileLocation),new Size(300,300)); 
            return new Bitmap(fileLocation);
        }

        private void _pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _isMouseDown = true;
            _mouseDownLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
        private void _pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isMouseDown)
            {
                _xDifference = _mouseDownLocation.X > e.X ? _mouseDownLocation.X - e.X : e.X - _mouseDownLocation.X;
                _yDifference = _mouseDownLocation.Y > e.Y ? _mouseDownLocation.Y - e.Y : e.Y - _mouseDownLocation.Y;
                _pictureBox.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        private void _pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _isMouseDown = false;
        }
        private void _pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
             _txtCenter.Text= _xDifference.ToString() + " - " + _yDifference.ToString();
             e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, _mouseDownLocation.X - _xDifference, _mouseDownLocation.Y - _yDifference, _xDifference * 2, _yDifference * 2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got you right this will draw an ellipse with center as the point where mousedown caught,while you drag the mouse in mouse move event to expand or not the ellipse it will be centered at the point caught by mousedown location.About the radious it will be in the picturebox,in the code(inside mousemove event)i placed the 2 variables Xdiff and Ydiff to get the job done and also it shows their values in the form caption(always updating as you move),and their values are the radious of x and y because note you might draw an oval ellipse:

```
    bool ismouseDown = false;
    Point p;
    int Xdiff, Ydiff;
    Bitmap bmp;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\..\YourImage.jpg");
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = Xdiff.ToString() + " - " + Ydiff.ToString();

        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, p.X - Xdiff, p.Y - Ydiff, Xdiff * 2, Ydiff * 2);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ismouseDown = true;
        p = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ismouseDown)
        {
            Xdiff = p.X > e.X ? p.X - e.X : e.X - p.X;
            Ydiff = p.Y > e.Y ? p.Y - e.Y : e.Y - p.Y;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ismouseDown = false;
    }
```

Comment: @terryBozio,Thanks for replying. I have included my code as per your answer as an edit above. Please see the function RenderImageOfSpecifiedSize(string fileLocation).Uncomment the line inside its body and I get radius different which should be same no matter what the image size is(be it larger than picturebox or smaller than it). I'm more concerned about the mousedown location which would serve as the center for the circle.How would you store this center unaffected by the image size. My other objective is also to display the radius (unaffected by panning of the image too).

Comment: you can just do this: _pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\2 duck.bmp");....the rest of the code works just fine,because the graphics object is drawing on the picbox surface so the coordinates remain the same after picture resize,just in case i tried with placing buttons to change the sizemode of picbox and remained the same points and radious.